# Can I use 22/4 wire instead of 20/2 wire?

Tags: electrical

My central vacuum system needs 20/2 stranded low voltage wire (24 volts I think).  Can I use 22/4 wire and pair-up two each to equal or better 20/2?  I could save some money by using surplus 22/4 wire.

Answer (score 9):

For power delivery through copper wires for this type of load the amperage capability of the wire is proportional to the cross sectional area of the conductor. You can check this in a [standard AWG wire table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes).

Your existing 20 awg wire has an area of .518 mm<sup>2</sup>. On the other hand a 24 awg wire has an area of .205 mm<sup>2</sup>. So two 24 awg wires @ .410 mm<sup>2</sup> would not be equivalent to the 20 awg wire.

It is possible that your system would work OK with the pairs of 24 awg wires if the current draw in the wires did not come close to the total capacity of the originally specified 20 awg wire but I would suggest that instead you try to either find some actual 20 awg wire, use surplus wire that had paired 22 awg conductors or find 6 conductor cable with the 24 awg conductors and set them up in two sets of triplets.

---

Update. I misread the original posting as specifying 24 awg wire instead of 22 awg. Sorry about that. The fact still remains that two 24 awg wires in parallel are not up to the same current capacity as the 20 awg wire. However a pair of 22 awg wires, each with a with a cross sectional area of 0.326 mm<sup>2</sup>, will be more than the equivalent of a 20 awg wire. So now you know that a pair of 22's or a triplet of 24's will suffice as a substitute.

Comment: I have a ton of leftover Cat6e wire, would that meet the requirement?

Comment: The asker said his surplus wire is 22 AWG (0.326 mm^2), not 24 AWG.

Comment: Yes, that's right...22/4 paired-up to use in lieu of 20/2, thanks.

Comment: **NEC 2008 110.12 Mechanical Execution of Work.** *Electrical equipment shall be installed in a neat and workmanlike manner.*  Would this be considered "*neat and workmanlike*"?

Comment: @Tester101 - Good question!! Another question. Does NEC 2008 110.12 apply to low voltage applications or only mains deployed wiring?

Comment: @MichaelKaras It applies to **all** wiring.

Comment: @Tester101 : All pairs would still be in a nice, neat single sheath, with merely a joined pair either at a screw terminal or inside a wirenut.  My answer is, "Yes, it's in a neat and workmanlike manner."

Comment: @Bob While it may be "*neat*", I'd argue it's not "[*workmanlike*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workmanlike)".

Comment: @Tester101 - I see your point, and perhaps it is outside the purest letter of the law.  If I paid retail to have the product installed, then I'd expect the designated material.  But if I'm doing it myself, and I have a perfectly safe, perfectly functional material available for free, then I wouldn't hesitate to use it.  And I think the whole point of this website is to shine light on those kinds of judgment calls.

Comment: @Bob I disagree.  The point of the website is for folks to learn the *correct* way to do things, not to learn how to hack things together.  DIY should not mean cutting corners.

Comment: @Tester101 - I just reread the FAQ's and I actually think you're pretty much correct.   It looks like my input may have been a little off-base for the nature of this forum.  I admit that I have more admiration for accomplished hackers than I do for seasoned code enforcement officers.

Comment: @Bob There is a time and a place for hacking. Being able to quickly repair virtually anything with limited resources is definitely a skill, but we like to focus on teaching folks how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified that you have surplus 22 awg wire.  A pair of 22 awg wires is more than equal to a single 20 awg wire.

Go for it.

Comment: I think the other answer, while incorrect because the it references 24AG not 22, still provides all of the necessary information to validate whether this is safe or not.  Can you make the same references to back up your claim?

Comment: I used the same reference as the other author.  And he has now corrected himself.